# In what way is it possible to align objects and texts in varying fields?

Tags: html, css

In what way is it possible to align objects and texts in varying levels and fields? Particularly, I tried adjusting the text to the quarter part of a website.

Here is a display of what I am implying - [DISPLAY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYXuF.png)

Rephrasing the question - in the code, I need two separate text blocks positioned below the headers - "Products" and "Quality".

```
#contentheadings {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-around;
        padding: 30px;
        font-family: "Arial";
        color: red;
        line-height: 100px;
    }
<div id="contentheadings">
        <div><h1>Quality</h1></div>
        <div><h1>Products</h1></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's better to have some code shown as to what you're trying to achieve instead of just a screenshot. Also the wording of the question is making it difficult to understand what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. On your note, I have edited the question and added a snippet of my code. Mind to review?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I understand what you're trying to get at but feel free to let me know if this isn't what you had in mind. I'm not sure why you had `line-height: 100px;` on the `#contentheadings` div so I removed that to match the image.

```css
#contentheadings {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: space-around;
 padding: 30px;
 font-family: "Arial";
 color: red;
 text-align: center;
}

#contentheadings div {
 padding-left: 30px;
 padding-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="contentheadings">
 <div>
  <h1>Quality</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut vitae tempor dolor. Quisque nec molestie orci. Mauris turpis ipsum, congue quis iaculis sit amet, eleifend non lectus.</p>
 </div>
 <div>
  <h1>Products</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut vitae tempor dolor. Quisque nec molestie orci. Mauris turpis ipsum, congue quis iaculis sit amet, eleifend non lectus.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```